# Iterate through ListView and get EditText-Field values android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am not able to get the ids of the editText fields within the list view, when the listViw grows more then the screen size and it has to be scrolled

Comment: Please be more accurate. I cannot link Your topic to Your post at all.

Comment: elaborate your question..

Comment: ListView doesn't create views until its requested to appear on screen (We scroll ListView to make request fot views to be appear on screen). You can tag id with one of the data member of your Model Class which you are passing in the ListView as a data

Comment: Please include more details or be more accurate otherwise it would be closed with "Unclear what you are asking"!